# Tableau map shapes overlapped

Tags: css, dictionary, tableau-api

I am trying to render some geographic data onto the map in Tableau. However, some data points located at the same point, so the shape images of the data points overlaps together. By clicking on a shape, you could only get the top one.

How can we distinguish the overlapped data points in Tableau? I know that we can manually exclude the top data to see another, but is there any other way, for example, make a drop down list in the right click menu to select the overlapped data points?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. But why exactly would you have multiple data points on the same spot? Different locations referring to the same geographical coordinates? Cause you can always change those coordinates to prevent overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to deal with this issue.

Some choices you can try are:

- Add some transparency to the marks by editing the color shelf properties. That way at least you get a visual indication when there are multiple marks stacked on top of each other. This approach can be considered a poor man's heat map if you have many points in different areas as the denser/darker sections will have more marks. (But that just affects the appearance and doesn't help you select and view details for marks that are covered by others)
- Add some small pseudo-random jitter to each coordinate using calculated fields. This will be easier when Tableau supports a rand() function, but in the meantime you can get creative enough using other fields and the math function to add a little jitter. The goal here is to slightly shift locations enough that they don't stack exactly, but not enough to matter in precision. Depends on the scale.
- Make a grid style heat map where the color indicates the number of data points in each grid. To do this, you'll need to create calculated fields to bin together nearby latitudes or longitudes. Say to round each latitude to a certain number of decimal places, or use the hex bin functions in Tableau. Those calculated fields will need to have a geographic role and be treated as continuous dimensions.
- Define your visualization to display one mark for each unique location, and then use color or size to indicate the number of data points at that location, as opposed to a mark for each individual data point